# Setting up IPSEC on LAN between two hosts (OpenBSD)

Tags: ipsec, openbsd

**I originally asked this on ServerFault, but got nothing. Hoping there are some OpenBSD experts here**

Trying to use IPSEC between two hosts on a LAN. **No VPN involved**

Using OpenBSD 5.8 (in VirtualBox). I'd prefer to use OpenBSD's built-in support for IPSEC and not a third-party.

Two hosts: `10.0.2.10` (host "A") and `10.0.2.11` (host "B")

They can ping/ssh each other before trying to setup IPSEC.

Copied A's `/etc/iked/local.pub` to B's `/etc/iked/pubkeys/ipv4/10.0.2.10`
Copied B's `/etc/iked/local.pub` to A's `/etc/iked/pubkeys/ipv4/10.0.2.11`

On both:

```
echo "ikev2 esp from any to any" > /etc/iked.conf

chmod 640 /etc/iked.conf

echo "ipsec=YES" > /etc/rc.conf.local

echo "iked_flags=" >> /etc/rc.conf.local
```

Check configuration:

```
/sbin/iked -n
Configuration OK
```

I'm confused as to what to do next. I think I need to setup `/etc/ipsec.conf` , but I've only found IKEv1 documentation out there.

Restarted both machines. No errors. Says iked daemon started. If I rename the public keys to anything, can still ping each other, so IPSEC doesn't seem to be working.

1. What else do I need to configure?
2. Are there logs for IPSEC and iked, and if so, where can I find them?
3. How to tell if IPSEC is working once configured, without looking at packets between the machines?

UPDATE:

I got IPSEC working without IKED (I think?):

`/etc/ipsec.conf`:

```
flow esp from 10.0.2.10 to 10.0.2.11

esp transport from 10.0.2.10 to 10.0.2.11 \
spi 0xCAFEBABE:0xCAFEBABE \
authkey 0x64CHARHEX:0x64CHARHEX \
enckey 0x64CHARHEX:0x64CHARHEX
```

hex needs to be in all uppercase

```
chmod 640 /etc/ipsec.conf

ipsecctl -F (delete config)
ipsecctl -f /etc/ipsec.conf (load config)
ipsecctl -s all -v (show config)
```

I'd prefer to use IKE's automatic keying. What can I do?

Comment: I really don't think `from any to any` will get you anywhere, you need to specify your peers, especially if you know their IPs beforehand.